# How to initialise my designated class once for every iteration in cell for row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, design-patterns, cell-formatting

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    WARedeemReward *reward = [self feedForIndexPath:indexPath];

    WARedeemRewardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellRedeemRewardsType];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[WARedeemRewardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellRedeemRewardsType];
    }
    /*How to make sure rewardView model is also initialise once for every cell for row call*/
    if (rewardViewModel == nil) {
        NSString *redeemRewardViewModelType = [[AWPViewFactory sharedInstance] getValue:@"WARewardHistoryViewModel"];
        rewardViewModel = [[NSClassFromString(redeemRewardViewModelType) alloc] initWithReward:reward];

    }
    /*How to make sure rewardView model is also initialise once for every cell for row call*/

    [WARedeemRewardCellDataBinder setData:rewardViewModel forCell:cell];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

I want to maintain initialisation of `rewardViewModel` in such a way that it is initialise only once for each `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  call. Something like cell's dequeue may be.

If I keep instance variable `rewardViewModel` then it will be initialise only once, and in next iterations of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, same instance will be reused again and again.

If I remove instance variable and make local variable `rewardViewModel` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then it will `alloc init` every time, which I do not want. Something like below:

```
WARewardHistoryViewModel *rewardViewModel;
NSString *redeemRewardViewModelType = [[AWPViewFactory sharedInstance] getValue:@"WARewardHistoryViewModel"];
rewardViewModel = [[NSClassFromString(redeemRewardViewModelType) alloc] initWithReward:reward];
```

How to initialise my designated class once for every iteration in cell for row?

Comment: I'm not saying it'd be a clean solution,but as a poc idea wouldn't adding model property to your cell class solve the problem?

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks but that will break my purpose of my clean cell subclass. I had done that and that was working.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of rewardViewModel just like your data source before calling `reloadData` on your `tableView`. In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[WARedeemRewardCellDataBinder setData:[self.yourRewardModelArray objectAtIndex : indexPath.row] forCell:cell];
```

This will ensure your reward models are created only once.